# Передача в компонент в качестве параметра - функции vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

У меня есть компонент

```
<template>
  <button class="btn" type="button">
       <slot></slot>
  </button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {

    }
  }
}
</script>
```

И есть также в компоненты в которых я использую это компонент Button

```
<template>
  <v-button post-title="hello" class='button' @click="methodClick">
  </v-button>
</template>
```

Как мне передать в компонент Button из другого компонента methodClick. Это надо для того чтобы для каждого button реализовать свой обработчик click

Comment: а разве прям так не работает?

Answer (score 1):

Есть 3 варианта:

## 1) Через $emit('click')

Добавьте в

```
<button class="btn" type="button">
    <slot></slot>
</button>
```

**@click="$emit('click')"**, чтобы вышло так:

```
<button class="btn" type="button" @click="$emit('click')">
    <slot></slot>
</button>
```

Теперь можно передавать слушать событие так:

```
<v-button post-title="hello" class='button' @click="methodClick">
</v-button>
```

## 2) модификатор *.native*

Можно легко слушать события корневого элемента компонента через модификатор *.native*

## 3) Продвинутый способ `v-on="$listeners"`

Через `v-on` можно ставить слушателей которые в объекте. $listeners это список слушателей которые запрашиваются у компонента. То есть, те слушатели которые ставятся компоненту автоматически ставятся на элемент у которого `v-on="$listeners"`. Vue замечателен

#### Все 3 варианта:

```js
var component1 = {
  template: `<button class="btn" type="button" @click="$emit('click')">
    <slot></slot>
  </button>`
}
var component2 = {
  template: `<button class="btn" type="button">
    <slot></slot>
  </button>`
}

var component3 = {
  template: `<button class="btn" type="button" v-on="$listeners">
    <slot></slot>
  </button>`
}

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: { component1, component2, component3 },
  data: () => ({
    count: 0
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app" style="height: 1000px; background: yellow;">
  Вы нажали но кнопки: {{ count }} раз <br>
  
  <component1 @click="count++">
    Вариант 1
  </component1>
  
  <component2 @click.native="count++">
    Вариант 2
  </component2>
  
  <component3 @click="count++">
    Вариант 3
  </component3>
</div>
```

Comment: Лучше сделать так:
```
<button class="btn" type="button" v-on="$listeners">
    <slot></slot>
</button>
```
Это позволит навешивать и другие обработчики, без явного указания *.native*.

Comment: @yarkov_aleksei спасибо, это очень удобно!